# Vue.js/Nuxt.js Load Fallback Image on 404

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I am trying to set a default image (placeholder image) in case the image resource is not found (404). I have a dict article which has a value for the key author_image. So that string is not empty but it just can't load that image.

In my template:

```
<img
 :src="article.author_image"
 alt="Author Image"
 @error="setFallbackImageUrl"
>
```

In my methods:

```
methods: {
    setFallbackImageUrl(event) {
        console.log('Image failed to load, setting fallback.')
        event.target.src = '~/assets/icons/avatar.svg'
    }
}
```

I can see in my console log that setFallbackImageUrl is called but the image src is not updated. I made sure that the `avatar.svg` is actually correct, if I just hard code that over `article.author_image` that works.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: That's strange: [it work's in an example that I've set up](https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/uh2qes45/). Can you check from your browser's network tab if the image is being loaded correctly? Is there, by any chance, that the `article.author_image` changes after the `setFallbackImageUrl(()` is invoked?

Comment: what does `console.log(event.target)` look like?

Comment: @Terry the image doesn't load if you open it in a tab, it is an incorrect URL path that points to my endpoints image without having the full url <img data-v-6fb28ef5="" src="/files/Employee-Picture_JohnDoe.png" alt="Author Image">.

Comment: This only works for images with a url, not for missing images in assets or static folder.

Answer (score 1):

The issue comes while loading your image via vue loader and webpack as the file extensions (.png, .svg, etc) are not module requests ([read more about handling assets with vue loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#asset-url-handling)).

You'll need to wrap it in the require to access it. the example by @Toni Michel Caubet works because he is using a link.

This Works for me.

```
methods: {
    setFallbackImageUrl(event) {
        console.log('Image failed to load, setting fallback.')
        event.target.src = require(`~/assets/icons/${'avatar' + '.svg'}`)
    }
}
```

Note: it's not needed to wrap the image in "${'avatar' + '.svg'}" i just removed my dynamic values and added "avatar".

Comment: This only works for images that are not handled via webpack or static folder. The original src needs to be a url and not called via require or ~/assets or ~/static.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is hitting a brick wall with webpack (files from assets/static)
The accepted answer from here should resolve it:

[Dynamic img src URL with "OR" statement not working properly in NUXT component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027817/dynamic-img-src-url-with-or-statement-not-working-properly-in-nuxt-component/68027966#68027966)