# Vuetify application breaks upon failed v-img source require statement

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

**Say I have `v-img` component and I want to render image source using `require()` statement.**

```
<v-img :src="require(`@/some-folder/my-img.png`)"></v-img>
```

**However, my application breaks completely if I don't have `my-img.png` in the folder.**

So far I've tried:

```
<v-img :src="require(...) || require(...)"></v-img>
```

```
<v-img :src="require(...)">
   <template v-slot:placeholder>
      // placeholder component.
   </template>
</v-img>
```

```
<v-img :src="resolveHandler()"></v-img>

methods: {
   resolveHandler() {
      let image;
      try { ... } catch (error) { ... } finally { ... };
      return image;
   }
}
```

None of the above worked. Any suggestion please? Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic img src URL with "OR" statement not working properly in NUXT component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68027817/dynamic-img-src-url-with-or-statement-not-working-properly-in-nuxt-component)

Comment: @kissu No the `try...catch` approach did not work for me.

Comment: @kissu Actually my function was a promise and it wasn't returning a string value. I made it synchronous and now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<template>
  <v-img :src="imageSrc">
    <template #placeholder>
      No image
    </template>
  </v-img>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    try {
      this.imageSrc = require(...);
    } catch (e) {
      this.imageSrc = null;
    }
  },
};
</script>
```