# Cannot find module when loading non existing assets

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm trying to load images from a Nuxt component (not a page) like below:

```
<img
  :src="require(`~/assets/logo/${imageCode}.svg`)"
  @error="$event.target.src = require('~/assets/logo/error.svg')"
/>
```

But when an image doesn't exist, I'm getting the following error in the browser's console:

> Error: Cannot find module './123.svg'

How should I deal with non-existing assets ?

Comment: I've answered it someday. Forgot the exact name of it. Couldn't find it with a search?

Comment: @kissu indeed, I've read that it works with Nuxt `pages`, but not with `components`, not sure how I should deal with it.

Comment: Wait, what is missing here? The component or the image?

Comment: @kissu the image is missing

Comment: Checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027966/8816585